# GIN: inject an array of objects

Tags: gwt-gin

Is there a way to inject an array of objects or collection of objects?

```
@Inject
private A[] objects
```

How do I create bindings for this case in my GinModule?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class YourModul extends AbstractGinModule {    
    @Provides
    public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
        final List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        integers.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
        integers.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
        integers.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
        return integers;
    }
}
```

The list of integers can now be injected as usual:

```
public class YouGinClass {

    @Inject
    private List<Integer> integers;

}
```

The `getIntegers()` is invoked everytime when a list of integer should be injected.